# Block Hash and Nonce generated by GenesisH0 python script is incorrect

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, altcoin, proof-of-work, genesis-block

After running GenesisH0 python script to generate the Genesis block for a local testnet (using v0.15.1), I got the following results.

merkle hash: 09a3e8eee58b90dba48f458a5e6bc04359b3630bbebdd5289c11818c756d5417

pszTimestamp: Yahooo 02/Feb/2018 SUV's accelerator sticks at speeds up to 100 mph

pubkey: 04678afdb0fe5548271967f1a67130b7105cd6a828e03909a67962e0ea1f61deb649f6bc3f4cef38c4f35504e51ec112de5c384df7ba0b8d578a4c702b6bf11d5f

time: 1518480000

bits: 0x1d00ffff

nonce: 3318186986

genesis hash: 0000000007783526b2049ea1ce5720e6f7486a9bb48a60bb2e93b892dd229984

When placing this information in chainparams.cpp and running the bitcoind after compiling it failed. The nonce produced by the script produces a different block hash when CreateGenesisBlock is executed.

Does anyone know why this script no longer works to create the genesis block for version v0.15.1?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add -v option putting the coin reward value and multiply it with * 100000000. Example you have a block reward of 50 it would be -v 5000000000.

python genesis.py -a scrypt -z "Yahooo 02/Feb/2018 SUV's accelerator sticks at speeds up to 100 mph" -p "04678afdb0fe5548271967f1a67130b7105cd6a828e03909a67962e0ea1f61deb649f6bc3f4cef38c4f35504e51ec112de5c384df7ba0b8d578a4c702b6bf11d5f" -t 1518480000 -n 0 -v 5000000000 -b 0x1e0ffff0

Try this and it will give you the correct Genesis hash. Note I replaced the nonce with zero, you can put another nonce on it or just let it be.